# How to use querydsl-sql-spring under gradle?

Tags: gradle, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

Is there any documentation or example available, how to use **querydsl-sql-spring** with **gradle**?
Or if someone could post the required parts of the buildscript?

I am not able to figure it out....

I am using spring-data-jpa-1.9.4 and gradle 2.11.

**EDIT-0:**

I naively tried this (just to try something...):

```
buildscript{
  dependencies{
    classpath 'com.querydsl:querydsl-sql-spring:4.0.9'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'querydsl-sql-spring'

// other stuff...

dependencies{
    // other dependencies...
    compile 'com.querydsl:querydsl-sql-spring:4.0.9'
}
```

and that yields error: `Plugin with id 'querydsl-sql-spring' not found`

Maven instructions are here:

- http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/latest/reference/html/ch02s03.html
- http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/latest/reference/html/ch02.html#d0e132

How do the same in gradle?

**EDIT-1:**

Some background info:

Dependencies starting with `com.mysema.query.**` is querydsl-3.x

Dependencies starting with `com.querydsl.**` is querydsl-4.x

The Spring-team has implemented an integration with querydsl-3.x only, which is working fine,
but they have now deprecated it, and say Spring-team will never support querydsl-4.x.

Instead they refer to the querydsl-team's solution: querydsl-sql-spring (querydsl-4.x).
That's why I would like to migrate over to that...

Comment: I dont find any example or documentation at all how to configure in build.gradle -- only maven examples...

Comment: You can't just add the dependency like you would any other dependency in gradle? `compile 'com.querydsl:querydsl-sql-spring:4.0.9'`

Comment: @johnktims --- querydsl has a processing-step in the build, generating classes dynamically, so there must be sthg more than just the dependency --- but I added some more lines to my question above...

Comment: `querydsl has a processing-step in the build`
Not necessarily though, I actually do not recommend the exporting of schemas in every build(databases are a little slow). For annotation processing it's fine though.

Comment: Why are you trying to use it as a gradle plugin? It might be best if you state what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: @RubenDijkstra --- I would prefer not to depend on any dbschema analysis at all -- is it not possible to only depend on the Entity-annotations (like the spring-team's solution) when using querydsl-sql-spring?